# Extract 7z archive to same folder as rar

Tags: shell, 7zip

How can I get 7z to extract the contents of a rar archive to the folder where it found the files?

I tried this and it just extracts to whichever folder I have my session in:

```
find ./ -name '*.rar' -exec 7z x -r {} \;
```

I want it to recurse through a set of folders and extract archives to the folder(s) where it found the archive.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux usage questions should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Answer (score 0):

find . -name '*.rar' -execdir 7z x -r {} \;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).